# Cálculo de sub-redes e hosts

Tags: redes, matemática

Não estou conseguindo entender como calcular isso:

> Determine a quantidade máxima de sub-redes, quantidade máxima de hosts por sub-rede, e para o endereço IP informe o endereço de sub-rede, endereço de broadcast, faixa de hosts válidos para a sub-rede, do seguinte endereço IP:
>
> ```
> 10.8.7.1/16
> ```
>
> A mascara de sub-rede é: `255.255.0.0`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199512/subnet-mask-how-to-segment-three-separate-networks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu consegui fazer, esta ai a resposta para quem quiser conferir:

Quantidade de Subredes: `2⁸ = 256 subredes`

Quantidade de Hosts válidos: `2¹⁶ = 65536 - 2 (broadcast e endereço da rede) = 65534 endereços válidos`

Endereço de Rede: `10.8.0.0`

Hosts Válidos: `10.8.0.1 até 10.8.255.254`

Broadcast: `10.8.255.255`

Para  confirmar, podemos utilizar esta calculadora: http://www.gwebtools.com.br/calculadora-subrede